# How to navigate to different routed and go back dismiss to self route?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have several nested navigator with above structure:

StackNavigator

- authNav
- homeNav

  - main(default)
  - create

    - subCreate1(default)
    - subCreate2
    - subCreate3
  - list

    - subList1(default)
    - subList2

Actually I play to navigate it. It's work as I expected.
But when I stay on `subCreate3` screen, I want to navigate to `subList1` screen, then when back or dismiss from `subList1` it should go to `main` screen not go to `subCreate3` again.
any idea with this ?. thank react-native user :D

Answer (score 0):

Navigation has stack of all the pushed screen, So when we will try to dismiss or goBack then it will navigate to top stack screen.

In your case, subCreate3 is top most screen when you are on subList1. So it will move there.

If you need to move to particular screen, then below is the logic:

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate(YOUR_SCREEN_NAME)
```

For more information, checkout [navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html)

Answer (score -1):

when you navigate to screens using `navigate` screens are pushed to stack and when you go back it goes back to the previous screen in the stack. In your case `subCreate3` is the previous screen in stack.
If you want to go main screen you have to use `navigate` function again.